# Program 6 of 49 the first 6 don't include a duplicate and 7th number has to be no one of the 1st 6

Tags: java, random, int

The 7th number displayed separate. So in my opinion I can't put the 7 numbers in one array.

I want to print the 1st 6 in a line and the 7th number separate.

Can someone help?

The first 6 numbers are between 1 - 49 and sorted low-high and do not contain a duplicate.

The 7th number is no one of the first 6 but between 1 - 49 too.

I already generate a 7th number but sometimes it is a duplicate from one of the first 6.

This is the task :
Write a program that generates random numbers that I can enter on my next lottery ticket. When the program is started, it should generate 7 numbers. The first 6 are to be output in ascending order. The 7th number is the super number. It is issued separately. It is not sorted with .

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Random;
    public class RandomizedArrayExample
    {
        public static int[] zahlen = null;    
        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            Random W = new Random();
            try
            {
                zahlen = new int[6];
            
                Random y = new Random();
                int gesamt = 0;
                boolean status = true;
                while(status)
                {
                    int zahl = y.nextInt(49)+1;          
                    if(!isCompleted()){
                        if(!isDuplicate(zahl)){
                            zahlen[gesamt] = zahl;
                            gesamt++;
                        }else{
                            continue;
                        }
                    }else{
                        status = false;
                    }
                }
             
           
          } catch (Exception e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          }
          
          for(int q = 0; q<6-1; q++) {
              for (int j = q+1; j<zahlen.length; j++) {
                 if(zahlen[q] > zahlen[j]) {
                    int k = zahlen[q];
                    zahlen[q] = zahlen[j];
                    zahlen[j] = k;
                 }
              }
          }
          
        String ihreZahlen = "----Ersten 6 Zahlen----";
        String superZahl = "-------Superzahl-------";
        
        int x = W.nextInt(49)+1;
        System.out.println(ihreZahlen);
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(zahlen));
        System.out.println(superZahl);
      }
      public static boolean isCompleted(){
          boolean status = true;
          for (int i = 0; i < zahlen.length; i++){
              if(zahlen[i]==0){
                  status = false;
                  break;
              }
          }
          return  status;
      }
      public static boolean isDuplicate(int num){
          boolean status = false;
          for (int i = 0; i < zahlen.length; i++){
              if(zahlen[i]== num){
                  status = true;
                  break;
              }
          }
          return  status;
      }
    }
```

This is a sample output:

```
----Ersten 6 Zahlen----
[14, 16, 30, 38, 41, 45]
-------Superzahl-------
38
```

You see the 38 is a duplicate

Comment: I'd recommend to do something like: 1) Generate an array with 49 numbers 2) shuffle array 3) take the first 7 numbers from the array - I still don't understand what is stopping you

Comment: Please show a sample output from your program.

Answer (score 1):

When you do `int x = W.nextInt(49)+1;` you risk getting a duplicate as in your example output. Instead you need a loop where you again use `isDuplicate()` to check whether you got a duplicate and break out of the loop when you haven’t.

For a different and maybe batter solution there is nothing wrong with putting all 7 numbers in one array. You can always take them out from there into 6 numbers and 1 number. Here’s one way:

```
    Random w = new Random();
    int[] allNumbers = IntStream.generate(() -> w.nextInt(49) + 1)
            .distinct()
            .limit(7)
            .toArray();
    int[] numbers = Arrays.copyOf(allNumbers, 6);
    Arrays.sort(numbers);
    int superNumber = allNumbers[6];

    String ihreZahlen = "----Ersten 6 Zahlen----";
    String superZahl = "-------Superzahl-------";

    System.out.println(ihreZahlen);
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numbers));
    System.out.println(superZahl);
    System.out.println(superNumber);
```

Example output:

> ```
> ----Ersten 6 Zahlen----
> [6, 8, 12, 16, 35, 42]
> -------Superzahl-------
> 33
> ```

Answer (score 1):

Here you assign x a value without checking if it's a duplicate:

```
int x = W.nextInt(49)+1;
```

add some logic to check if it is not already in your "zahlen array". The easiest way would be to add a while loop beneath it and use your isDuplicate method to check if it is already in your zahlen array. As long as this is the case you assign x new values.

```
int x;
do{ 
   x = W.nextInt(49)+1;
}while(isDuplicate(x));
```